# SCRIPT5009: 'fetch' is undefined

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, internet-explorer, fetch-api

have some troubles! For my requests i'm using Fetch API!

Submit form don't work in IE, because of "SCRIPT5009: 'fetch' is undefined"!

Example how it's looks like:

> ```
> fetch("url",
>         {
>              method: "POST",
>              body: JSON.stringify(data),
>              headers: {
>                  'Accept': 'application/json',
>                  'Content-Type': 'application/json'
>              }
>          }).then(function (response) {
>              return response.json().then(function (data)
> ```

Same time in Chrome and FF it's works fine! I'm already trying to find some solutions surfing Google, but it was unhelpful!

I was tried to installing "isomorphic-fetch" and "es6-promise" in npm, and tried to import it in my .js file, but it was unsuccessful as well, console shows me this: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token import"! Btw, required() function don't work as well! So I'm totally don't now what to do, how to use these polyfill thing and all of that!

If some ones have an idea, thanks in advance!
BR!

Comment: It seems like `fetch` is not supported on IE. https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: Yup, as I under stand its about native Fetch! But what about packages from npm like "isomorfic-fetch" or "fetch-wg", those are pofylfill! But its now work for me, but works for others! Magic!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use https://github.com/github/fetch instead.

CDN: https://cdnjs.com/libraries/fetch

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fetch/2.0.3/fetch.js"></script>
```

If you need `Promise` polyfill you can use http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/install.html

```
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bluebird/3.5.0/bluebird.min.js"></script>
```

Load `Bluebird` before `fetch`:

```
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bluebird/3.5.0/bluebird.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fetch/2.0.3/fetch.js"></script>
```

Comment: Well, it's looks better than it was, but problem still actual! Now "'Promise' is undefined", this goes from fetch.js, from that script which you gived

Comment: lifesaver! I had to use both scripts, but worked like a charm.