# Error Promise is Undefined - Filestack API

Tags: javascript, api, file-upload, upload

I am using the Javascript v3 version of Filestack. I am not sure if this version is supported in IE11. I continue getting an error in the console that says "Reference Error: 'Promise' is undefined." Does anyone know what my problem might be?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SCRIPT5009: 'fetch' is undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44242051/script5009-fetch-is-undefined)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Filestack JS requires a Promise Polyfill.

You can use a script tag to pull in https://cdn.polyfill.io/v2/polyfill.min.js?features=Promise

Or install it using npm

```
 npm install promise-polyfill --save-exact
```